# How to build a Map<DateTime, List> from firebase data in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

i am trying to create a map as Map from firebase.

I tried this

```
    Future<Map<DateTime, List>> getlist() async {
        QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection("${_username.toLowerCase()}-orders")
        .getDocuments();
        var list = new List.generate(querySnapshot.documents.length, (int index) => querySnapshot.documents[index]['date']);
        var datelist = list.toSet().toList();
        var map = new Map.fromIterable(datelist,
    key: (item) => DateTime.parse(item),
    value: (item) => () async {
      QuerySnapshot querySnapshot2 = await Firestore.instance
        .collection("${_username.toLowerCase()}-orders")
        .where('date', isEqualTo: item)
        .getDocuments();
      var ordlist = new List.generate(querySnapshot2.documents.length, (int index) => querySnapshot2.documents[index]['name']);
      return ordlist;
    });
    print(map);
    return map;
  }
```

I get an error like this

```
The return type 'Map<DateTime, () → Future<List<dynamic>>>' isn't a 'Future<Map<DateTime, List>>', as defined by the method 'getlist'.dart(return_of_invalid_type)
```

Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `value:` argument you have a typo. What you wrote is `(item) => () async {...}` when you likely meant `(item) async {...}`. What you wrote is an arrow function, that returns a function.

Even after that what you'll have is a `Map<Datetime, Future<List<dynamic>>` and you'd need to resolve all those `Future` to get a `Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>>`. I note that you're doing a new query for each date, but I *think* you should already have those values available after the first query...

It looks like [`groupBy`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/groupBy.html) from `package:collection` would get you pretty close, you'd still need one more `.map` call to extract the `'name'` field...

```
Future<Map<DateTime, List>> getlist() async {
  var querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance
      .collection("${_username.toLowerCase()}-orders")
      .getDocuments();
  var items = querySnapshot.documents;
  var grouped = groupBy(items, (item) => item['date']);
  var map =
      grouped.map((date, item) => MapEntry(DateTime.parse(date), item['name']));
  print(map);
  return map;
}
```

Comment: it shows an error in MapEntry(DateTime.parse(date), item['name'])); it says 'name' must be an integer

Comment: The result shows as Instance of Document snapshot in the list

Comment: Thank u but change item['name'] to new List.generate(item.length, (int index) => item[index]['name']) it works now